# Free VPN for ubuntu 16.04 that connects to UK

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, vpn

I'm looking for a free VPN that works on ubuntu 16.04 and connects to UK, I just need to use it for a few seconds each month to connect to my UK spottily account so that I could login, that's all, just few seconds every now and then. I need to install it on the PC, not browser based so that Spotify application works.

I used to use pptp, but you can't tell when a server is up and when it isn't, on windows I use tunnel bear, but won't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: There exist similar questions on this site but they are either obsolete or don't connect to UK or aren't free.

Comment: Have you tried [tor](https://torproject.org)? and set the exit node tu UK using : ```ExitNodes {uk}``` in torrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that TunnelBear can be used on ubuntu, I followed [this article](https://www.tunnelbear.com/blog/linux_support/),

1. Basically just download the openvpn file they linked to in the
   article, at this moment [it's this one](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tunnelbear/linux/openvpn.zip) and unzip it
2. Import it like you import any OpenVPN settings, by choosing the country you want to connect to, I picked `TunnelBear United Kingdom.ovpn`
3. Enter your TunnelBear username and password

I just found [Auto OVPN](https://github.com/yomun/auto-ovpn) too for gnome users, I haven't tried it because I'm not using gnome but it seems decent

Answer (score 0):

In order to have TunnelBear work with Ubuntu 18.04,
I have had to change "dev tun0" to "dev tun"
in all of their *.ovpn configuration files 2nd line.
Otherwise, trying to open a VPN raised the following in sylog:

```
nm-openvpn[9431]: ERROR: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun0: Device or resource busy (errno=16)
```

nm-openvpn[9431]: Exiting due to fatal error